# List of Greek-Roman decrees against Jewish rituals in ancient Israel

Tags: history, anti-semitism

I'm confused by the prevalence of the Talmudic accounts of various Greek/Roman administrative decrees against the Jews and Jewish rituals/Torah study. On the other hand, most of the historical material I meet shows relative tolerance or indifference.

Where can I find a list of rulers/years when such decrees were issued?

Comment: Did you look in מסכת תענית?

Comment: @IsraelReader Can you be more specific, please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_persecution_in_the_Roman_Empire#Judaism

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write **מגילת תענית** https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA/%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: See also [books of the Maccabees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_the_Maccabees).